# Vue.js handle multiple click event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, vuejs2, vue.js

I have a list and want to handle a click event for each item in the list

```
<ul>
  <li 
    v-for="item, index in items" 
    :key="index"
    @click="select(item)"
  >
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the script is

```
...
methods: {
  select(item) {
    console.log('Select', item)
  }
}
```

This works well when there are about 10 items. However, when there are about 1000 items, the performance becomes very slow because I attach 1000 events for 1000 items.

The solution is to attach only one click event for the list and use `event.target`

```
<ul @click="select($event)">
  <li 
    v-for="item, index in items" 
    :key="index"
  >
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In function `select`, how can I get `item` corresponding to each item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
<ul @click="select($event)">
  <li 
    v-for="item, index in items" 
    :key="index"
    :id="index"
  >
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your `select`:

```
select($event) {
  console.log('Select ', $event.srcElement.id)
}
```